# Keras model inside other model

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am creating a Keras model like this one:

```
model_1 = Model(inputs=[input_1], outputs=main_network)
```

This model will be used for predictions, but not for training. Instead, this model will belong to a larger on:

```
error = Subtract()([y, model_1.output])
model_2 = Model(inputs = model_1.inputs+[input_2], outputs=error)
```

Where the variable y is the output of other layers. I have checked that both models are correctly built and they both have the right layers, but when I train model_2, the weights of the layers in model_1 are not updated. I thought they would, since the layers in model_1 and model_2 should be the same instances (in fact, they are using the same addresses). What can I do so the weights of both models update at the same time?
Thanks!!!

EDIT: there was a mistake in the code

Comment: It's impossible to see any connection between model 1 and model 2 from the code you posted. Could you provide enough information about your models?

Comment: There was a mistake in the code, I have edited and fixed it.

Comment: Did you make model_1 or any of its layers untrainable anywhere in your code?

Comment: One of the layers in model_1 is not trainable, and there are several which have no parameters (Add, Reshape ...). I have checked that model_2 can train, since the weights in the layers change, while it does not happen in model_1.

Comment: Did you figure it out eventually? I think I have the same issue...